# Having Issue on Passing PHP Token to jQuery Ajax and PHP File

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have file like

```
<?php
session_start();
$token = md5(rand(1000,9999)); 
$_SESSION['token'] = $token; 
?>
```

and a jQuery Ajax call like

```
var passRequest = $('#email-pass-request').val();
var data = {
            requestedPass: passRequest,
            token: '<?php echo $token; ?>'
};
var passRetrive = $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "assets/app/passrequest.php",
                            cache: false,
                            data: data,
                            dataType: "html",
                            beforeSend: function() {
                                console.log(data);
                            }

});
passRetrive.done(function(data) {
    $("#pass-request-result").html(data);
});
```

so as you can see I am trying to pass the `$token` session variable into jQuery ajax data like

```
var data = {
                requestedPass: passRequest,
                token: '<?php echo $token; ?>'
            };
```

but this looks not working since in `beforeSend()` I am getting  this in console

[image]

and eventually nothing in

```
passRetrive.done(function(data) {
  $("#pass-request-result").html(data);
});
```

and finally the `passrequest.php` is like

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$token = $_POST['token'];
echo $token;
```

Comment: are your file is .php or .html?

Comment: is your javascript code in a file with php extension?

Comment: are you sure that all codes that you posted were in one file? any externaljavaScript file? or same file with all code above?

Comment: well I am using an external js file but it is registered in .php

Comment: @Akam, I have a `login.php` file with an external js file which I am registering it like `<script src="js/login.js"></script>`

Comment: Try `var tok = "<?php echo $token; ?>" ;`  and after use the varibile tok

Comment: Ok, then here is the problem coming from! the login.js can't execute php code!

Comment: even if we regiter it in the page?

Answer (score 0):

PHP code **inside .js files** is not by default parsed by PHP engine.

There are some ways to make them parsed by PHP, usually involving **.htaccess** directives if you are using **apache** web server. It's different if you are using **nginx**.

[Here you have a simple way](http://mycodesite.com/processing-external-js-file-with-php/) to load **javascript** and parse them as PHP before serving, involving no messing up with the web server.